# CreateML: "The document could not be saved."

Tags: xcode11, macos-catalina, createml

I am getting following error with CreateML with testing output on a Image Classifier project:

"The document  could not be saved. You don’t have permission. 
To view or change permissions, select the item in the Finder and choose File > Get Info."

Software version:
Xcode 11.0 beta 7 (11M392r)
Catalina 10.15 Beta (19A546d)

What I have done so far:

1- Made sure I have full permission to the file in Finder

2- Followed this tutorial for troubleshooting permission:
https://www.macworld.com/article/2978282/when-save-as-says-you-dont-have-permission.html

3- Removed file out of iCloud zone, to make sure iCloud is not messing up anything.

However, I am still getting this message and cannot use CreateML.

Appreciate any help! : )

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to System Preferences > Security & Privacy. Click the Privacy tab, and find Full Disk Access on the left. Here you need to add CreateML. You'll likely want to add the Terminal as well.

Comment: PERFECT! Thanks so much mate